# Allow factory executed code to raise events when that code is a `Func<TIn, TOut>`?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, constraints

I'm building a retry system that allows me to attempt code multiple times before giving up (useful for things like establishing connections over the network). With this, the basic code I usually copy and paste everywhere as a base is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < attemptThreshold; i++) {
    try {
        ...
        break;
    } catch (Exception ex) { ... }
}
```

There's quite a bit of logging code within the `try` and `catch` blocks that can be delegated by refactoring to ensure consistency. It's straightforward to refactor it and delegate the work of retrying:

```
public static class DelegateFactory {
    public static bool DelegateWork<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, TOut> work, int attemptThreshold, TIn input, out TOut output) {
        if (work == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(...);

        for (int i = 0; i < attemptThreshold; i++) {
            try {
                OnMessageReceived?.Invoke(work, new FactoryEventArgs("Some message..."));
                output = work(input);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) { OnExceptionEncountered?.Invoke(work, new FactoryEventArgs(e)); }
        }

        return false;
    }
    public static event EventHandler<FactoryEventArgs> OnMessageReceived;
    public static event EventHandler<FactoryEventArgs> OnExceptionEncountered;
}
```

Calling it is also straightforward:

```
DelegateFactory.DelegateWork((connectionString) => {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        conn.Open();
}, 10, "ABC123", out bool connectionMade);
Console.WriteLine($"Connection Made: {(connectionMade ? "Yes" : "No")}");
```

Keep in mind, the above code excludes the definition for `FactoryEventArgs`, but it's just a `class` that takes an `object` as an argument (for simplicity in prototyping). Now, what I have above works just fine, but I wanted to add a way to allow the caller to post messages using an event for the factory's subscriber to log (the whole single responsibility thing, which I'm still learning, by the way, so be gentle). The idea is to create an event called `OnMessageReceived` and a public method called `PostMessage` that can only be called from code being executed by the factory. If the call is made from any other place then it would throw an `InvalidOperationException` to signify that the call was invalid. My first though to accomplish this is to use the call stack to my advantage:

```
using System.Diagnostics; // Needed for StackFrame
...
public static void PostMessage(string message) {
    bool invalidCaller = true;
    try {
        Type callingType = new StackFrame(1).GetType();
        if (callingType == typeof(DelegateFactory))
            invalidCaller = false;
    } catch { /* Gracefully ignore. */ }

    if (invalidCaller)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(...);

    OnMessageReceived?.Invoke(null, new FactoryEventArgs(message));
}
```

However, I don't know for sure that this would prove to be reliable. The idea though is to allow the work to also send messages to the subscriber, but that may be a moot point because the object containing the work could just raise it's own `OnMessageReceived` event instead. I just don't like the idea of the exceptions being sent to the subscriber one way, and messages going out another. Maybe I'm just being picky? Starting to have a smell, the more I think on it.

**EXAMPLE USE CASE**

```
public class SomeObjectUsingTheFactory {
    public bool TestConnection() {
        DelegateFactory.DelegateWork((connectionString) => {
            // Completely valid.
            DelegateFactory.PostMessage("Attempting to establish a connection to SQL server.");
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                conn.Open();
        }, 3, "ABC123", out bool connectionMade);

        // This should always throw an exception.
        // DelegateFactory.PostMessage("This is a test.");
        return connectionMade;
    }
}
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        DelegateFactory.OnMessageReceived += OnFactoryMessageReceived;
        var objNeedingFactory = new SomeObjectUsingTheFactory();
        if (objNeedingFactory.TestConnection())
            Console.WriteLine("Connected.");
    }
    public static void OnFactoryMessageReceived(object sender, FactoryEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
    public static void OnFactoryExceptionOccurred(object sender, FactoryEventArgs e) {
        string errorMessage = (e.Data as Exception).Message;
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred. {errorMessage}");
    }
}
```

In the example above, if we assume the connection continues to fail, the output should be:

> Attempting to establish a connection to SQL server.
>
> An error occurred. {errorMessage}
>
> Attempting to establish a connection to SQL server.
>
> An error occurred. {errorMessage}
>
> Attempting to establish a connection to SQL server.
>
> An error occurred. {errorMessage}

If it succeeds on the second attempt it should be:

> Attempting to establish a connection to SQL server.
>
> An error occurred. {errorMessage}
>
> Attempting to establish a connection to SQL server.
>
> Connected.

---

How can I ensure the method `PostMessage` is only called by code being executed by the factory?

**NOTE:** *I'm not against changing the design if it's introducing bad practice. I'm completely open to new ideas.*

**COMPILER ERRORS**: Also, any compilation errors in here are strictly oversights and typos. I manually typed this question up as I tried my best to work my way through the problem. If you encounter any issues, let me know and I'll fix them promptly.

Comment: You lost me after being able to call `DelegateFactory.DelegateWork`. Given the current design (and ignoring compilation errors for the moment), how would `PostMessage` be called when used *properly*? It's unclear what you're trying to prevent because there's no indication of the exposure.

Comment: *"The idea is to create an event called OnMessageReceived"* - you have that, good. Now, since you mentioned it in the same sentence, how does PostMessage relate to that in terms of code?

Comment: @madreflection I will notify you again once I post an update, but I believe the solution to this question technically creates a code smell so I'm working on a different path until I can prove to myself this version doesn't introduce a smell. Oh, and yes the `SqlConnection` was just an example.

Comment: @madreflection I've added an example use case. `PostMessage` relates to `OnMessageReceived` in that it raises that event on the factory for subscribers, which is why I believe there's a smell. At this point, I'm thinking the event should live on the caller and the subscriber can just subscribe to the caller too (in the example use case `SomeObjectUsingTheFactory` would get it's own `OnMessageReceived` and the subscriber would listen for it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do away with the stack-based security by introducing a context object that provides access to the event.

But first, a few notes.  I'm not going to speak to the merits of this design because that's subjective.  However, I will address some terminology, naming, and design matters.

1. .NET's naming convention for events does not includethe "`On`" prefix.  Rather, the method that *raises* the event (marked `private` or `protected virtual`, depending on whether you can inherit the class) has the "`On`" prefix.  I've followed this convention in the code below.
2. The name "DelegateFactory" sounds like something that create delegates.  This does not.  It *accepts* a delegate and you're using it to perform an action within a retry loop.  I'm having a tough time word-smithing this one, though; I've called the class `Retryer` and the method `Execute` in the code below.  Do with that what you will.
3. `DelegateWork`/`Execute` return a `bool` but you never check it.  It's unclear if that's an oversight in the example consumer code or a flaw in this thing's design.  I'll leave it to you to decide, but because it follows the `Try` pattern to determine if the output parameter is valid, I'm leaving it there *and using it*.
4. Because you're talking about network-related actions, consider writing one or more overloads that accept an awaitable delegate (i.e. returns `Task<TOut>`).  Because you can't use `ref` or `out` parameters with async methods, you'll need to wrap the `bool` status value and the return value of the delegate in something, such as a custom class or a tuple.  I will leave this as an exercise to the reader.
5. If an argument is `null`, make sure you throw `ArgumentNullException` and simply pass it the name of the argument (e.g. `nameof(work)`).  Your code throws `ArgumentException`, which is less specific.  Also, use the `is` keyword to ensure you're doing a reference equality test for `null` and not accidentally invoking overloaded equality operators.  You'll see that in the code below, as well.

---

**Introducing a Context Object**

I'm going to use a partial class so that the context is clear in each snippet.

First, you have the events.  Let's follow the .NET naming convention here because we want to introduce invoker methods.  It's a static class (`abstract` and `sealed`) so those will be `private`.  The reason for using invoker methods *as a pattern* is to make raising an event consistent.  When a class can be inherited and an invoker method needs to be overridden, it has to call the base implemention to raise the event because the deriving class doesn't have access to the event's backing storage (that could be a field, as in this case, or perhaps the `Events` property in a `Component`-derived type where the key used on that collection is kept private).  Although this class is uninheritable, it's nice to have a pattern you can stick to.

The concept of raising the event is going to go through a layer of semantic translation, since the code that registers the event handler may not be the same as the code that calls this method, and they could have different perspectives.  The caller of this method wants to post a message.  The event handler wants to know that a message has been received.  Thus, posting a message (`PostMessage`) gets translated to notifying that a message has been received (`OnMessageReceived`).

```cs
public static partial class Retryer
{
    public static event EventHandler<FactoryEventArgs> MessageReceived;
    public static event EventHandler<FactoryEventArgs> ExceptionEncountered;

    private static void OnMessageReceived(object sender, FactoryEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageReceived?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    private static void OnExceptionEncountered(object sender, FactoryEventArgs e)
    {
        ExceptionEncountered?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Side note: *You might want to consider defining a different `EventArgs`-derived class for `ExceptionEncountered` so you can pass the whole exception object for that event rather than whatever string data you cobble together from it.*

Now, we need a context class.  What will be exposed to the consumer is either an interface or an abstract base class.  I've gone with an interface.

The semantic translation from "post a message" to "a message was received" is aided by the fact that `FactoryEventArgs` is unknown to the lambda that's posting the message.  All it has to do is pass the message as a string.

```cs
public interface IRetryerContext
{
    void PostMessage(string message);
}

static partial class Retryer
{
    private sealed class RetryerContext : IRetryerContext
    {
        public void PostMessage(string message)
        {
            OnMessageReceived(this, new FactoryEventArgs(message));
        }
    }
}
```

The `RetryerContext` class is nested in the `Retryer` class (and private) for two reasons:

1. It needs access to at least one of the invoker methods that's private to the `Retryer` class.
2. Given the first point, it simplifies things by not exposing a nested class to the consumer.

Generally speaking, nested classes should be avoided, but this is one of those things that they're exactly designed to do.

Also note that the sender is `this`, i.e. the context object.  The original implementation was passing `work` as the sender, which is not what's raising (sending) the event.  Because it's a static method in a static class, there was no instance to pass before and passing `null` probably felt dirty; strictly speaking, the context is still not what's raising the event, but it's a better candidate than a delegate instance.  It will also be passed as the sender when being used inside of `Execute`.

The implementation needs to be modified just slightly to include the context when invoking `work`.  The `work` argument is now a `Func<TIn, IRetryerContext, TOut>`.

```cs
static partial class Retryer
{
    public static bool Execute<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, IRetryerContext, TOut> work, int attemptThreshold, TIn input, out TOut output)
    {
        if (work is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(work));

        DelegationContext context = new DelegationContext();

        for (int i = 0; i < attemptThreshold; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                OnMessageReceived(context, new FactoryEventArgs("Some message..."));
                output = work(input, context);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                OnExceptionEncountered(context, new FactoryEventArgs(e.Message));
            }
        }

        output = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

`OnMessageReceived` is called from two different places: `Execute` and `PostMessage`, so if you ever need to change how the event is raised (maybe some add logging), it only needs to be changed in one place.

At this point, the problem of preventing unwanted message posting is solved because:

1. The event can't be raised arbitrarily since anything that calls it is private to the class.
2. A message can only be posted by something that has been given the ability to do so.

Small nit-pick: *Yes, the caller could capture a local variable and assign the context to the outer scope, but then someone could also use reflection to find the event delegate's backing field and invoke it whenever they want, too.  There's only so much you can reasonably do.*

Finally, the consumer code needs to include the context in the lambda's parameters.

Here's your example use case, modified to use the implementation above.  The lambda returns a `string`, the connection's current database, as the result of the operation.  That's distinct and separate from the `true`/`false` returned to indicate whether it was a success after `attemptThreshold` attempts, which is now what's assigned to `connectionMade`.

```cs
public class SomeObjectUsingTheFactory
{
    public bool TestConnection(out string currentDatabase)
    {
        bool connectionMade = Retryer.Execute((connectionString, context) =>
        {
            // Completely valid.
            context.PostMessage("Attempting to establish a connection to SQL server.");
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                return conn.Database;
            }
        }, 3, "ABC123", out currentDatabase);

        // Can't call context.PostMessage here because 'context' doesn't exist.

        return connectionMade;
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Retryer.MessageReceived += OnFactoryMessageReceived;
        var objNeedingFactory = new SomeObjectUsingTheFactory();
        if (objNeedingFactory.TestConnection(out string currentDatabase))
            Console.WriteLine($"Connected to '{currentDatabase}'.");
    }
    public static void OnFactoryMessageReceived(object sender, FactoryEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
    public static void OnFactoryExceptionOccurred(object sender, FactoryEventArgs e)
    {
        string errorMessage = (e.Data as Exception).Message;
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred. {errorMessage}");
    }
}
```

As further exercises, you could also implement other overloads.  Here are some examples:

An overload for a lambda that doesn't need to call `PostMessage` and therefore doesn't need the context.  This has the same type for the `dowork` parameter as your original implementation.

```cs
public static bool Execute<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, TOut> work, int attemptThreshold, TIn input, TOut output)
{
    return Execute((arg, _ /*discard the context*/) => work(arg), attemptThreshold, input, out output);
}
```

Overloads for lambdas that don't need need to return a value in an output parameter, and therefore use `Action` delegates instead of `Func` delegates.

```cs
public static bool Execute<TIn>(Action<TIn, IRetryerContext> work, int attemptThreshold, TIn input)
{
    // A similar implementation to what's shown above,
    // but without having to assign an output parameter.
}

public static bool Execute<TIn>(Action<TIn> work, int attemptThreshold, TIn input)
{
    return Execute((arg, _ /*discard the context*/) => work(arg), attemptThreshold, input);
}
```

Comment: Holy thank you! This is a fantastic solution, and a very, very detailed answer! I love it through and through! Thank you so much for taking the time to write it up! I will definitely be awarding a bounty to your answer when I can! I understood everything through your use of examples and thorough explanation. I actually have no remaining questions for clarity which is a nice bonus to me! Again, thank you for writing such a detailed answer!

Comment: Bounty incoming in 24 hours. Thanks again!

Comment: That's way above and beyond. Not gonna lie, I've read your comment dozens of times and it continues to deliver dopamine hits. *That's* motivation.

Comment: @Tacoタコス: Thank you so much for your generosity. I am truly humbled and I hope I can be of service again someday.